# How to apply different functions to columns based on data type using cx_Oracle in python?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'd like to export an Oracle table to csv, doing some transformations based on column types (say on DATE fields).
How can I do that? This code exports the table, but how do I iterate through fields, and check data types?

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect(<user>, <psw>, <db>)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from mytable")

with open(<filename>,'w',encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
   writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";", lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
   
   # Header:
   writer.writerow([col[0].lower() for col in cur.description])
   #writer.writerow([col[1] for col in cur.description])
   
   # Data:
   for row in cur:
       writer.writerow(row)

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The data section should be rewritten like this:

```
   # Data:
   for row in cur:
       lst = list(row)
       for i in range(len(lst)):
          if cur.description[i][1].name == 'DB_TYPE_DATE':
                lst[i] = myfunction(lst[i])
       writer.writerow(lst)
```